# Raster Tile to Vector Tile

Tags: mapping, gis, mapbox, raster, vector-tiles

I've been google-searching trying to find an approach, or a set of existing tools, for taking a mercator raster data-tile and converting it to a vector tile (by, for instance, creating polygon-like iso-line features via marching squares or whatever and packing it into a protocol buffer).  I have a web-mercator backend service that produces raster png tiles (of raster weather data), and I would like to figure-out how to also create vector tiles from the same tile data, on the fly preferably.

Mapbox-ish/Mapnik tool-sets seem like a natural starting point, but I'm just going to ask here to see if anyone can set me on the immediate right path.  It's not obvious to me from googling around.

Comment: I'm still trying to figure this out.... any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: gis.stackexchange.com might be a better place for general GIS questions that aren't about a specific programming problem.